# Screenshot of current page using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Duplicate:

> [website screenshots using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php/757721)

Is it possible to take a screenshot of the current page using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on windows. There's [imagegrabscreen()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php)

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't render the page, the browser does.

[Here is a list of tools](http://mashable.com/2007/08/24/web-screenshots/) that let you do what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

No*

- PHP runs on the web server not on the client where the browser is and cannot control the browser or other portions of the operating system remotely.

Answer (score 2):

You could install [webkit2png](http://github.com/paulhammond/webkit2png/) *on your server* and then execute `webkit2png http://yourpage.example.com` from your PHP script. That will give you a screenshot the way Webkit renders the page. For installing on Linux, [see this](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/).

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you could write a HTML layout engine as a PHP extension, and use that... But, no, there's nothing already in PHP that'll do what you want.

You could use [a command-line utility like this](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) and call it from PHP.

Comment: There is a HTML layout engine in PHP called HTMLTOPS: http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm , but then you'd have to convert the resulting PostScript file to an image; that is workable but complex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat Firefox add-on: [Screengrab!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows platform, you can install ACA WebThumb ActiveX: 
http://www.acasystems.com/en/web-thumb-activex

A simply demo:

```
<?php
  // PHP html to image.
  // This script shows how to convert the google.com homepage to a PNG image file.
  $WebThumb_Maker = new COM('ACAWebThumb.ThumbMaker')
    or die("Start ACAWebThumb.ThumbMakerfailed");

  $WebThumb_Maker->SetURL("http://www.google.com"); 
  if ( 0 == $WebThumb_Maker->StartSnap() )
  {
    // Tanke snapshot successful, call SetImageFile() to save the image as a PNG file.
    echo "Take snapshot successful." ;
    $WebThumb_Maker->SaveImage("google.png");
  }
?>
```