# How to convert HTML to image with PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screenshot of current page using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834445/screenshot-of-current-page-using-php)

How to convert HTML to image with PHP , have idea!!!

Comment: Do you mean "make a screenshoot using PHP" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of 'Use PHP to cook spaghetti carbonara' as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Python, PyQt4 and Webkit installed *on your server*, you can use [Webkit2PNG](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/) to do this: it downloads the page, fires up the Webkit rendering engine, and takes a snapshot.

Note that this could be resource-intensive; also, rendering can differ in various browsers (and in IE).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an image of a web page, you need software that can render a web page (that is, lay out elements, apply styles, and so on). Such software is typically called a "browser".

It's possible to automate a browser from PHP, using COM (like in sAc's answer) on windows, for example.