# shell tool which renders web site including javascript

Tags: javascript, linux, shell, browser, rendering

we want to test our webpages on linux shell. For that reason I'm looking for a shell tool, which gets the html page from server (like 'wget') and then executes contained Javascript, include pictures and so on. After this, the tool should give me a 'screenshot' of the rendered page, so that I can create a checksum for that screen. (So I want to the same as opening browser in Windows, open webpage and make a screenshot after page load, but on linux)
Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Comment: Try searching SO for "website thumbnail" or "webpage screenshot" - this has been asked many times. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=website+thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

If you meant "commandline tool", perhaps [webkit2png](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/) would work. Note that it uses Webkit rendering engine, so you'll see how the site would look on Safari or Chrome. See also [khtml2png](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

[wkhtml2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)