# PHP: get frame from SWF to JPEG or GIF

Tags: php

How get frame from animate SWF to JPEG(or better animate GIF), using PHP. Possible using ffmpeg? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a video movie embedded in a flash file, or a real flash animation?

Comment: simple animation in swf, like animated gif

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible without using a Windows box to open the file and capture a screenshot of the file. If you can convert the `.swf` to `.flv` then you can use `ffmpeg` to pull a frame, but if it is something like a game, well yea you are sort of out of luck unless you can setup (or are on) a Windows box.

I will try and find my code I used for windows to capture a screenshot, which worked in Windows 7 and XP and post it here, will have to wait till later as I do not have access to my backup files right now.

You might also take a look at this thread: [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)