# php---how the site publish the thumbnail

Tags: php, javascript

i want to konw how this site (www.retailmenot.com)publish the thumbnail. the thumbnails are under "Today's Top Coupons" part.do they first use a screenshot software to get the site image down and save it then publish it. but this way will have too trouble.am i right?

Answer (score 1):

[9 Ways to Put Site Screenshots in Your Web App](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2008/07/10/9-ways-to-put-site-screenshots-in-your-web-app/), and if you are interested in doing this without a third party, check out this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)