# HTML - Taking screenshot and pasting in email

Tags: html, email, screenshot, mailto

I have a mailto link in HTML which when clicked, opens an email to IT Support. Is it at all possible to have a screenshot of the screen automatically copied and pasted into this email, without any action from the user?

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy + paste an image directly into the mail client if using a `mailto:` link.  If however you build a support email form, which sends the email server side from your webserver, using methods described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php) it will be possible to automatically include a screenshot of the site.