# How can I get the thumbnail of a website?

Tags: php, ajax, thumbnails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

I want to create a script that will show the thumbnail of a site (let's say 400*300px ). I don't want sites like www.bitpixels.com .

So the answear could come in 2 ways:
1) You explain how could I take the screenshot of a website (using only PHP,ajax, etc,... no .NET or other stuff like that :D )

2) You know a website that offers this type of service for free and there's no limitation in the number of thumbs you can get, or their size.

Comment: This has been answered already: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+screenshot

Comment: This seems kinda' overwhelming for the server... Maybe it's worth paying that extra 5$ for a thumbnailing service? :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) (webkit-based html to pdf conversion), it also contains wkhtmltoimage, a version of it that outputs images. It's open source and if you have any sort of dedicated machine you should be able to use it. Otherwise I am not sure. Since it is webkit based it should provide you with a decent rendering of the page too.

Another great tool for this is [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/)

Comment: No, I have a shared hosting, can't install this plugins :D . But thanks for the answear

Comment: You could get yourself a virtual server or something, there are affordable ones.

Comment: We'll see. I'm just starting a project, but I think I'll only need a VPS in 6-7months or so. I'll stick to the thumbnailing services till then :D.

Comment: Thanks Seldaek, yes `wkhtmltoimage http://google.com google.png` worked for images