# Are there any available PHP script that can grab a screenshot of the url?

Tags: php

Like what browsershots.org did they can have a screenshot of the url i have inputted are there any available script like that?

Comment: None that I know of... have you tried Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do with [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) and its [`wkhtmltoimage`](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltoimage-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2) variant:

```
exec("./wkhtmltoimage http://example.org/ image.png");
```

Note that the output filename must be in a writable location.

Comment: @mario how to use it?DO i have to install the wkhtmltoimage to my server?

Comment: @khem: Try reading the [manual](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html).

Comment: @khem: Yes, someone has to install it. Click the link, download, extract the tool. It's no effort really.

Comment: @khem: In any local directory. It's not a Windows app, btw. You will have to find something more fiddly for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: @mario I will put it on my file server..I don't have any experience in installing app on file server except PHP scripts.This is my directory ...
cgi-bin
logs
Maildir
public_html
streaming
.bach_history
.bash_logout
Where to put it? the location of my script is here /public_html/gpslocnfo

Comment: @khem: Same directory as the php script from which you want to use it.

Comment: @mario the filename is wkhtmltoimage-amd64

Comment: Or just install it anywhere and use an absolute path if you are that unsure how and where PHP executes.

Comment: in rendering the outputis it right to do it this way? <?php exec("./wkhtmltoimage http://example.org/ /thumb/image.png");  echo "<img src=\"/thumb/image.png\" />"; ?>

Comment: no output...in my directory there are no image.png that exist.

Comment: It must be a writable location. Try out `exec("./wkhtmltoimage 'http://google.com/'  /tmp/test.png");`. If that gives no result in /tmp, you need to adapt the path `./` to the tool still.

Comment: @mario thanks it works...now got a problem with setting height and width in the documentation it say --scale-h --scale-w $e = exec("/home/gpsradio/public_html/locnfo/wkhtmltoimage  'http://google.come/' --scale-h200 --scale-w200 /home/gpsradio/public_html/locnfo/image.gif"); it won't work.

Comment: @khem: I've never really used the scaling feature, only the crop options. But I think you need a space between the `--scale-h 200` option and number, and also `--scale-w 200`. If that doesn't work or the result looks odd I would advise that you scale it using the GD functions, or imagemagik with `exec("mogrify --resize 200x200 .../image.gif");`