# Is there anyway to capture a print of a webpage and save it server-side?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, dom

So, I'm basically working on a custom card editor. The user can edit the text (in place), upload a picture and do basic editing (resizing, framing, b&w). This is all done via javascript. When the user is done editing the card, I need to be able to capture a screenshot of the whole page as it is and store it server-side. This is very important - this process is NOT for the user. I want to receive an image or a pdf of the page exactly as the user edited it.

Is this possible in any way?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly with a `<canvas>`-based setup, but with standard HTML/Javascript, not really.

Comment: also possible with `flash` or `svg`+`javascript`

Comment: Possible copy of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php). Please see that post for the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to have the browser make a screenshot and send it to you (which would be the only reliable way). What you *can* do is save all the states on submit. Your application is javascript written and all they do is manipulate variables like width/height/rotation. If you can dump all the final states of the variables that your script keeps track of you should be able to recreate a static version of the page that is the equivalent of what the user has done with it.
How the user's browser has rendered this is an entirely different story.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I guess I'll have a little more trouble than I was expecting but oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to replicate the user's browser, the plugins, the level of zoom they use, the color of their scrollbars...

I would keep a server-side copy and a client-side copy of the document.  When the user does something to the client-side copy, the server-side copy gets updated (maybe an ajax request would supply the information about what changed).  Then, you have two similar copies, one of which you can turn into a pdf.