# Generating jpg or png from an html web page with PHP

Tags: php, html, linux, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

I am trying to write a script that will take a list of urls and generate screencaps of them.  I have searched around and am unable to find anything that will reliably accomplish the task.  I am running PHP 5.3 on a Linux box.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it need to be done server side ? There are a lot of browser plugins and other libraries that will let you script something like this.

Comment: something like this maybe? http://blog.hazardousgaming.info/119/displaying-the-website-thumbnail-on-mouse-over

Comment: That thumbalizer does work, thanks Claudiu.  I would still like to find something that I don't need a 3rd party service for.  Thumbalizer charges money over a certain amount of requests per month.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to do that, but one of the easiest ways I have found is to use [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/). They have an example of it on their website.

Comment: I need to have the script run as a cronjob and fetch images of the sites to save to disk.  Not sure if I can get a js library to function server-side, but I will play around with this later tonight and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @JZ: It's not a JavaScript library. It's a program that runs a JavaScript script, which can do things to a webpage, like load it and then render it.