# How to convert a php page in to jpeg file and to download

Tags: php, html, jpeg

I am trying to convert a web page into jpeg image file. i had used following codes.

```
<?php    //put your html code here
$html_code = "
<html>
<head>
 <title>My test title</title>
 <style>
 body {
 font-family:verdana;
 font-size:11px;
 color:black
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 this is the body
</body>
</html>";

// Create the image
$img = imagecreate("300", "600");
imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0);
$c = imagecolorallocate($img,70,70,70);
imageline($img,0,0,300,600,$c);
imageline($img,300,0,0,600,$c);

$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($img, 9, 0, 1, 1, $white, "VERDANA.TTF", $html_code);

// Display the image
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);

?>
```

**Question:** Is there any library to convert html page into image ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need an HTML renderer for this. There exists a few such renderers, but most of them requires an X server on your web server, so check out Xvfb to run a framebuffer device without a screen.

Answer (score 2):

GD does not do this natively, you can render a picture from your screen though but that is as far as it goes.  I had [painty](http://www.rabuser.info/painty.php) in my links with a description of html to jpg php conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to internally render the page. You can find possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php).

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to 'screen-capture' an HTML table as an image a few months back, *I couldn't find anything suitable*.

I eventually settled for writing my own code using PHP's GD library with GIF output.

It was for a very specialised purpose and I'm sure it wouldn't suit an application outputting jpegs.

Comment: What about an HTML to PDF to IMG? Depending on the complexity of the display, I would imagine this might work for some cases.

Comment: Well, no, the HTML page was a table of coloured cells - a *wafer map* - and I wanted images I could embed in webpages. I spent months thinking about it, but it was simpler to implement than I expected.

Comment: This answer sounds like it came from imaginationland to me.

Comment: Maybe I'll think of a question and post my code. I wouldn't help anyone, though, it's too specialised.