# How to make a thumb of a website

Tags: php, linux, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

is it possible to make  a thumb of a website using php?

Like http://buysellads.com/buy they create the thumb automatically of each website.

How can I do?

THanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that *this* exact question has been asked many times before, e.g. here: [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Comment: Take a look at this question, it's about taking screenshots with PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Answer (score 0):

You need a browser engine that renders the websites. There is none written in PHP.

But there are some services out there that create the thumbs. You submit an URL and get the thumb back. That's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

see this:

http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/website-thumbnail-generator.php

http://webthumb.bluga.net/home

or:

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=76454

```
<?php echo "<img src="http://thumbnails.alexa.com/image_server.cgi?size=large&url=$siteurl">"; ?>
```