# HTML page to JPEG or GIF file

Tags: php, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

IF anyone knows or has a script that takes screenshots of a website let us know 
i need use only div,css,p,b,strong,br,hr,img tags support
like this code
http://www.rabuser.info/painty.php

Comment: JPEG or GIF? This *is* 2011, you know?

Answer (score 1):

Read some of the suggestions posted in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php).

There appear to be several scripts that will perform this for you, you just need to do a bit of research.