# Screenshot users display in a web application

Tags: php

What I want to implement is a web application with a video and a button, that every time a person clicks on that button I get/screenshot/anything else their display and save the jpg/or something on the server.

How can I do that? I heard you can't do that with javascript. I had an idea of a plugin/flash application? How can that be done? The application will be done in PHP.

Comment: Do you want to take a *real* screenshot of the the users screen? Or just take a snapshot of the video at the moment when the user hits the button?

Comment: This can be done in Java.  See [`Robot.createScreenCapture()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

Comment: You can't do this in PHP at all. If you want an answer re: flash, I suggest re-tagging your question.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: A snapshot of the video would be good too. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php is a server side scripting language, it has nothing to do with a end users desktop and computer... there is no way to do this with Php or straight html for that matter... you would have to utilize Java, Flash, or something else.

Furthermore, it sounds like what you want to do is a little sketchy in itself and maybe you should think why you want to do this.