# Full webpage screenshot from an unpublished site

Tags: html, screenshot, screen-capture, image-capture

I want to take a full screen shot of a webpage within the browser. The webpage is not published and is opened from my desktop. Is there any tool or way to do this?

Edit: I need to take a full screen shot of a long page, screenshot will only take half of it. I can do it in a published site within Google Chrome with webpage screenshot but this only works if the site is published.

Edit: So basically capture a full offline webpage, I can capture one half then the other and stick them together, but would rather use a tool that does it for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

1. "Printscreen" key
2. [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) using PrintScreen key or "Ctrl + Shift + P"
3. OneNote from MSOffice  (Win + S)
4. [Firefox Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/)

**EDIT:**

The Firefox Plugin called "FireShot" is awsome... just tried it!

Comment: can I open a html file in OneNote?

Comment: @user1060444  with one note you can capture your browser content as an image and it is placed as an image in OneNote.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows, a simple press of the Print Screen (<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>) key or <kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> will place a screenshot of the entire desktop or the active window onto the clipboard. From there, paste it into your favorite image editing software.

**Edit:** You could try the [Screengrab extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/), it looks like it's no longer being actively developed but there are comments about it still working. [Here is a write up of how to use it](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/create-screenshot-image-of-entire-web-page-in-firefox/).