# GD2 imagegrabscreen fatal error?

Tags: php, gd

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
$im = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($im, "myscreenshot.png");
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

And I as a result I get this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function: imagegrabscreen() in
>   c:\usr\krasnal\www\testy marcina\index.php on line 2

I am using apatch ver 2.7 instaled on windows 7.
And one more info about GD:

> GD Version: bundled (2.0.28 compatible)
>
> FreeType Support: yes
>
> FreeType Linkage: with freetype
>
> T1Lib Support: no
>
> GIF Read Support: yes
>
> GIF Create Support: yes JPG Support: yes
>
> PNG Support: yes
>
> WBMP Support: yes
>
> XBM Support: yes
>
> JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support: no

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least php 5.2.2 or later, and php_gd2.dll

Here is a code snippet to test on your server : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526834/1093649

And if you get a blank screen, please check **Apache service privileges** like stated on this [php manual page comment](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.imagegrabscreen.php#82630).

Answer (score 2):

Also:

> For this to work your Apache service must be set to 'Allow service to
>   interact with desktop' otherwise you will just get a blank image. To
>   fix this right-click My Computer, select Manage/Services and
>   Applications/Services - find the apache service (like Apache2) and
>   right-click, select Properties - choose the Log on tab and check the
>   'Allow service to interact with desktop' checkbox. Restart Apache.