# PHP : imagegrabscreen() not working on PHP 7.2.27

Tags: php, laravel, php-gd

I am using 7.2.27 PHP version with Laravel 7.

Below code working on my local same configuration,

```
$captured = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($captured, "~path/" . time() . ".png");
imagedestroy($captured);
```

But this code not working on live server it's throwing exception like,
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagegrabscreen() in ~file-path:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ~file-path on line 11**

I don't know what is the exact issue.

I also checked below answer but I don't know what is `php_gd2.dll`,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8715544/6656706

**Edit:**
I also tried on AWS ec2 with xampp but not working ! I also tried by installing `php_gd2.dll`.

Any help will be appreciated !

Thanks.

Comment: What's the OS of the server?

Comment: Did you installed php-gd library [right way](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php) on the server? Did you checked `phpinfo()` for supporting this library?

Comment: @Olivier Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: I wonder what you expect to see in that image

Comment: Yes, the screenshot is performed server-side of course, not client-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server is on Linux, it can't work because [imagegrabscreen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php) is only supported on Windows:

> **Note:**
>
> This function is only available on Windows.

Also note that the screenshot is performed on the server. It will not capture the user screen.

Comment: So  what about if I create instance of `Windows Server 2019` ?

Comment: @JaydeepMor If you call the function on a Windows Server, it will capture the screen of that server (which is probably not what you want to do).

Comment: exceptions exist ofc, i have a windows server where i call imagegrabscreen() regurarly.. because i have a MMORPG game client running there 24/7 playing a game when i don't have time :P

Comment: Okay so any alternative way for achieve this ? Actually I need to capture user screen (Windows only).

Comment: @JaydeepMor A browser can't take a screenshot. Why do you need that anyway?

Comment: Actually I have created one script for my organization for all employees. It is working locally as xampp saver installed locally. Now I got that is not possible from browser. Thanks a lot for all your kind help !