# Create image with php from HTML and CSS

Tags: php

I'm wondering if it's possible to convert markup (HTML and CSS) to an image with php? I want to let a user drag elements around, type in text etc then to allow them to hit save as image. If someone could tell me whether this is possible and any pointers to functions/tutorials on the matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Comment: I don't think PHP is a good fit for this. It sounds like it all should live in the browser.

Comment: See [Rendering web page into images](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2005/05/rendering-web-page-to-images_13.html), which does the job via javascipt. But it seems not to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Canvas element (html5), I have only just scratched the surface of my learning on it, but I am pretty sure that it, in conjuction with jQuery, and jQuery UI could achieve what you are going for.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would use standard html markup within the canvas tag, but you certainly can right click on them and save (as png)