# Google page preview

Tags: image, preview

is there any way to do something like google has?
I think preview of the page when you hover link.
I just want to know, on what it is based.

Image creating and php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.thumboo.com/ is free and has an API.
You could write a PHP/Javascript function to create the hover over effect.

Comment: You can't do it in pure PHP, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php