# Take a screenshot of a certain website at a given moment

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I want to take a screenshot from my website of another website or preferable 1 part of it (an object tag).

I want it to work this way: I click on a button that will send a request to screenshot the page at this moment. Several ideas are insert the page inside a flash object and screenshot it. Or opening a browser on the server and when I click the button send a request using AJAX to tell the server to screenshot with this browser.

How should I do this because I kind of failing right now with the flash Idea. The page I am trying to screenshot is a live camera that uses a .wvx object. But I can't even do that with a .swf object.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: We moved our techblog to Tumblr, here is the new link to the blog post: http://techblog.floorplanner.com/post/20528549445/server-side-png-rendering-of-swf-images-using-gnash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/). They have several examples of [renderding page output](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Rendering). It [supports plugins like flash](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Page_settings) too.

[`render()`](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface#render%28fileName%29) always renders the entire page. To just render one `<object>` tag, I guess you can do one of:

- create a page that only contains that `<object>` tag.
- use javascript to remove everything else.
- crop the final screenshot based on `<object>` page coordinates.

To use phantomjs from php, try [php-PhantomjsRunner](https://github.com/diggin/php-PhantomjsRunner).

Edit 1: In case you only want to render a flash file that does not actually rely on the web page it is in, you can try [Gnash](http://www.gnashdev.org/) according to the blog post ["Server-side PNG rendering of SWF images using Gnash" by Valentine Bichkovsky](http://techblog.floorplanner.com/2010/11/02/server-side-rendering-of-swf-images-using-gnash/).

[phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs) [screen-scraping](/questions/tagged/screen-scraping)

Comment: AFAIK from my practice with phantomjs, it does not capture Flash ok.

Comment: @Stan: that might also be a timing issue. Were the screen shots taken after the flash had loaded/rendered fully?