# Screenshot of server's desktop using PHP

Tags: php, windows, screenshot, desktop

Is there any way of taking screenshots of my server's desktop using PHP, so that they can be presented to my website's remote administration page?

I am running a Windows Server 2008, but would be interested in a *nix alternative aswell for future purposes.

Comment: *nix doesn't usually make a habit of running graphical environments on headless servers.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, just wanted to know though for my small red hat kde desktop, which I use as a server for personal purposes, although I don't really think it can be done without the use of an external program

Comment: I think you'd be better running an executable for KDE to do the screenshot, potentially using PHP to modify it afterwards if you wish. A quick web search should turn up a possible solution. (Edit: ditto for Windows too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will only work on Windows based servers, but how about:

```
<?php
// capture the screen
$img = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($img, 'screenshot.png');
?>
```

Or:

```
<?php
// Capture the browser window
$Browser = new COM('InternetExplorer.Application');
$Browserhandle = $Browser->HWND;
$Browser->Visible = true;
$Browser->Fullscreen = true;
$Browser->Navigate('http://www.stackoverflow.com');

while($Browser->Busy){
  com_message_pump(4000);
}

$img = imagegrabwindow($Browserhandle, 0);
$Browser->Quit();
imagepng($img, 'screenshot.png');
?>
```

Searching is useful for a fast answer ;)

[Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Comment: Image grab screen was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!