# Any Javascript or PHP libraries or tutorials for making an image out of a page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if there are any existing (ideally well documented) PHP or Javascript/jQuery libraries/plugins or tutorials for creating an image from a page. An example of this in existance is Zurb's [BounceApp](http://www.bounceapp.com/).

This probably isn't something that's oft used, however I'd love to incorporate this into a personal project of mine.

In my particular use case, I would have the CSS and HTML which would dictate the "image" available locally, so there would be no need to get the HTML mark-up of another page, then find it's CSS styles.

Any advice or pointers towards a helpful tutorial or plugin/extension would be very, very, very appreciated :).

Comment: Did you know about [`html2canvas`](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: There is a trick before `canvas`. Load the url in an iframe and put the iframe behind a transparent image with absolute position and lower `z-index`.

Comment: Props for the links guys. I should've thought of the word "screenshot", I'll check out the other question and html2canvas now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), it the newest solution for your needs.

You should check this implementation: http://hertzen.com/experiments/jsfeedback/

To crop the image, you can use [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) and send the info to a PHP script, to resize / crop the image the way you want.

Hope that helps!