# Live Thumbnails/Large Image

Tags: php, image, image-generation, dynamic-image-generation

Is there any way to get a certain thumbnail generated by PHP from a live given URI? I also would want to do this for the live on click image.

Comment: What do you mean by the "live on click image"?

Comment: When I click the thumbnail I want it to enlarge into a bigger image = lightbox

Comment: So you are asking two questions, then? A way to generate a thumbnail via php on a live uri (your site, or another site?), then when you click the thumbnail, a lightbox to view the full size image?

Comment: Another site and yes when clicked I want to load a fullsize image of the live site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form what i understand you want to generate thumbnail of a given website via its URL ???

If that is what you want then [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php) would help you

I prefer the Pure PHP option if you are using a windows server but if not then you would have to use 3rd party APU like http://www.thumbalizr.com/apitools.php

Another method is using HTML5 Canvas or Converting the site to PDF -> PNG or any image format

I hope this information helps

Thanks
:)

Comment: That looks mint are you able to do a html5 example?

Comment: I have looked at that but I am still confused on how to implement

Comment: Load the remote site into a page body then $('body').html2canvas(); to convert it to canvas .... are you using windows ??  why doen you use the pure PHP example ???