# How to get `thumbnails document` like google doc?

Tags: php, document, thumbnails, doc

How to get `thumbs document` (doc, docx, pdf, pptx, ppt,.....)?

May be use C#, php, .....

Please help me!
Thanks you very much!

Comment: I see word, portable document format and powerpoint documents in your listing, but not thumbs document. What is thumbs document and how is it related to the document types you've been listing? And please add a screenshot from or link to that google doc you refer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been asked before ... please see [Live Thumbnails/Large Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898407/php-live-thumbnails-large-image/9898934#9898934) for some examples

It only capture web sites but its the same for every other document types .... all you need to do is convert (doc, docx, pptx, ppt,.....)  to `pdf` or `HTML` or `image`  ... PDF is easier to work with but some online tools can also convert `doc` to `image` directly ..

When you have it `pdf` you can easy convert it to `jpg` then create a thumbnails form `jpg`

See more tools you can use

See

http://www.imagemagick.org/www/formats.html

```
exec("convert sample.pdf sample.jpeg")
```

See

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5846-PHP-Convert-PDF-documents-to-images-using-Ghostscript.html

See

[How do I convert a PDF document to a preview image in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php)

I hope this helps

Thanks

:)