# Turn an HTML page into an image?

Tags: php, html, image, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

I have a very simple HTML webpage, styled with some CSS and maybe a little Javascript.  Each time it loads it creates a unique "postcard" which I would like to be able to save as an image for download.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I know PHP doesn't do rendering, and that's the major issue.  Perhaps using some Javascript to take a "screenshot" are the page loads?

Comment: This question has been [asked here many times already](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+to+image+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

http://www.rabuser.info/painty.php#english