# Creation of Sprite Image using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a webpage that uses one large sprite. Instead of composing the sprite in photoshop or some third party software, I would like use HTML and CSS to arrange the images and then render the compilation as one single JPEG.

Is there anyway to accurately render an HTML page as a JPEG?

To clarify: Basically, I want to create a web page using html and css, render it as one single image, and then use that image as a sprite on a different web page. So I would just be compiling my "image" in HTML and CSS instead of building it in photoshop.

Comment: Your question is difficult to follow. Consider re-wording it.

Comment: Is this just a one time deal for you to generate a sprite, or do you want this to work for every visitor to your page?

Comment: I'm trying to create a template so that I can easily switch out details of a sprite such as changing one particular source image. But I'm using css styles such as border-radius and box-shadow on the individual images within the larger sprite, so it's very time consuming to do it in photoshop or third party

Comment: I finally found the answer I was looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called Print Screen. <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>

Comment: come on now...print screen won't accurately capture the dimensions so that the sprite coordinates (for the JPEG) are the same as the original CSS coordinates.

Comment: @WilliamSmith: You'd get a full image of your website, which is perfectly usable in sprites.

Comment: @WilliamSmith: If your website is large, there are plugins like `Awesome Screenshot` for chrome, that can automatically capture an entire page for you.