# Looking for a better index than index.html

Tags: php, javascript, apache, web

So I have a small web server where I store my php/javascript pages.

These pages are mainly just samples and practice files, but I am looking for a way to show previews of the pages.

Currently I use the default Apache index.html, which just provides a list of all the files in the directory.

I am looking for a page that has tiles of all the web pages and providers a preview of the file.

Or anything else that you may recommend as better.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read this: http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/?

Comment: Seems to let you play with index.html not do anything fancy with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's two that are close to what you want.  You can probably customize them a bit.

[PHP Directory Listing Script](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script)

[PHP Directory Listing](http://weitnahbei.de/php-directory-listing/)

Comment: Second Link has a good sample of pictures, now how can I auto generate images.....

Comment: To include thumbnails of pages, you will also need to implement a method of getting those screenshots. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Answer (score 0):

there may be a browser that has an option to output a screenshot of a given page that u could run on the server when the index file is requested but u would probably want to cache the screenshot

Comment: This is an apache server, why would I want to run a browser on it...?

Comment: because a page may be dynamic and to generate a preview of it would require a browser to load the page and save the contents of the viewport to an image

Answer (score 0):

You can use imagegrabscreen to create page preview
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php

Comment: Says its only useable in Windows. I would rather just use the snipping tool if I am going to be manually taking screenshots.