# Html to jpeg as thumbnail

Tags: php, javascript, html, screenshot, thumbnails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Can someone tell me how to take a thumbnail off of a web page using php or js without any 'API' support? Otherwise convert HTML to PS and PS to jpeg is also possible.
Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://wwww.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Since taking a screenshot will require interfacing with something that can take it — no, you can't do that without any API support.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your favourite answer (or upvote helpful answers in general), including the answers on your 4 other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Phantom JS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface). It can be used to render HTML from the commandline, using various output formats. Creating a thumbnail can be done by setting the zoom factor.

Comment: thank tou brother, i will check it out. is there a way with out running a script

Comment: What would you want to run instead of a script?

Answer (score 0):

[WKHtmlToImage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is able to render a webpage using webkit engine. You will have to launch an executable on server-side though.

Comment: thank tou brother,is there a way to do this without lounch an executable on server

Comment: See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-phpc).