# Determine website main colors

Tags: php, javascript

Can someone tell me the best way to determine the 5-6 most used colors in a website ( not an image ) using PHP and/or javascript. I've searched through the net, but all I could find was some third-party solutions ( which don't suit my needs ), and such that extract the color from an image.

I'll be grateful if you can help in any way.

Comment: Write a script to parse the color variables in the main CSS file of a site ?

Comment: Amyth this would be very underperforming, as the main css file can get quite big, and parsing it will be a pain in the ass. I didn't mention that I need a high-performance solution, as speed is viable and I'll be processing a lot of web sites at once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general strategy, [get a screenshot of the website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757778/19068) and store it in a lossless image format (e.g. PNG but not JPEG). Then loop over all the pixels and [get their colour](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php). Store the results in an associated array  (`( 'colour code' => 'count of pixels with that colour' )`). Loop over that array and find the highest counts. Those are your colours.

Answer (score 0):

Online Image Color Extractor:

- http://www.coolphptools.com/color_extract
- [http://jrm.cc/color-palette-generator/index.php](http://jrm.cc/color-palette-generator/index.php?image=rec/girl-with-umbrella.jpg&steps=3&method=precise)

Online Website Color Extractor:

- http://www.colr.org/ (Click "Other Stuff")
- http://www.colorcombos.com/grabcolors.html
- http://www.colorhunter.com/