# Generate PDF from a pagescreen

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I need to generate a PDF file from a pagescreen in my HTML5/Javascript project.
I've tried jsPDF but it's too hard to use it and I haven't found anything about creating tables.
Does somebody know something that do a simple screenshot of a webpage and convert it into a PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use tools like this one:
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

I've just found this thread about that:
[Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Comment: Thank you but I have no knowledge about PHP.
I just need a tool that take a screenshot of the page and convert it into a PDF automatically. I can't use the program indicated in the first link because I need the tool works on its own, not by user input.

Comment: Sorry then.. Can you just use File > Print and print it to pdf ?

Comment: I'm developing an app using cordova. It runs on iPad so I can't do this simply by using the browser.