# Take Screen Shot of a webpage via code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a website which generates HTML tags dynamically in a specific div. Now after all the HTML tags are created I save these HTML tags in Database. The problem is that I need to take the Screen Shot of the web page where the HTML Tags are generated. when I am about to save it, but;

1. I cant Imagine where to begin as far as the screen shot thing goes.
2. I don't want to use Third party API as what they generally do is ask for a url and then go to the website take a screen shot and then email it to you.

why I cant use them is because when i dynamically create HTML Tags they are just on the browser. if someone else try to access the same link they will get a page without the currently created HTML Tags (even if I refresh the page the tags are gone.).

I dont want a complete solution just a Tip on how to start building the solution for this problem, and by screen shot I mean Images.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the end goal? What are the screenshots for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Canvas/Javascript to take screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you're using HTML5, check HTML2Canvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)
- If you can access the server environment and install extra's on it, try wkhtmltoimage (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), it's sort of a web browser that you can run via command line, and specify the output. You can specify it to be an image, a pdf, or other things.

The bad thing is that you need somewhere to point it, but otherwise it's excellent for these kinds of things. But it doesn't have to be a public url, it could be used internally, or maybe even supply the html from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Use webshot library it is simple and easy to use. you can also use window.print() method to take screen shot of webpage