# Generate a JPEG from $html in JS and/or PHP

Tags: php, jpeg, screenshot

Want to get an image (JPEG) from $html variable in PHP.

Steps:

1. Transform my code to a canvas in HTML5
2. Transform my canvas in image.

I know the steps but I do not know how to code them.

I do not want to use wkhtmltopdf.

Thanks for your help.

PS: Saw that ([Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)) but it's not in HTML5.

--

EDIT:
Try to use this but do not work...

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.body;
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

Comment: I did not work because you cant do that. You need a service on the server that will take screenshots of a webpage and render it for you , like phantomjs , etc ....

Comment: $html is my PHP value that containing my html code page (from <html> to </html>).

Comment: mpm with HTML5 I can without render plugin. (i.e.: html5canvastutorials.com) :)

Comment: @Francois M well it doesnt work for you obviously since you are asking the question. You cant just with HTML5.

Comment: Just see this link (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html). i ll try this.