# how to wait for element visibility in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

Users click this link:

```
<span onclick="slow_function_that_fills_the_panel(); $('#panel').show();">
```

Now I'm simulating the click in phantomjs:

```
page.evaluate(
  function() { $("#panel").click(); }
);
console.log('SUCCESS');
phantom.exit();
```

Phantom exits before the slow function ends its execution and the DIV becomes visible. How can I implement waiting?

Comment: stupid solution is setTimeout()

Answer (score 26):

Heres a spin of Cybermaxs's answer:

```
function waitFor ($config) {
    $config._start = $config._start || new Date();

    if ($config.timeout && new Date - $config._start > $config.timeout) {
        if ($config.error) $config.error();
        if ($config.debug) console.log('timedout ' + (new Date - $config._start) + 'ms');
        return;
    }

    if ($config.check()) {
        if ($config.debug) console.log('success ' + (new Date - $config._start) + 'ms');
        return $config.success();
    }

    setTimeout(waitFor, $config.interval || 0, $config);
}
```

Example of use:

```
waitFor({
    debug: true,  // optional
    interval: 0,  // optional
    timeout: 1000,  // optional
    check: function () {
        return page.evaluate(function() {
            return $('#thediv').is(':visible');
        });
    },
    success: function () {
        // we have what we want
    },
    error: function () {} // optional
});
```

It's a little easier when you use a config variable.

Comment: THANKYOU! I spent two days trying half a dozen other ways of reliably checking to see if a form had been submitted (rather than a blindly hopeful `setTimeout`) and this is the only one that worked flawlessly for me. +1

Answer (score 15):

PhantomJS runs asynchronously by default, causing problems like the one you describe above (where the script finishes before your results are ready)

However there is nothing to stop you using it in a synchronous way.

Just use `phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove')` in a while loop. This will keep looping through the event pump until the webkit engine loads your page or processes any necessary browser events.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

// Step 1: View item
page.open('http://localhost/item3324.php');
do { phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove'); } while (page.loading);
page.render('step1-viewitem.png');

// Step 2: Add to cart
page.evaluate(function() {$('#add-to-cart').click(); });
do { phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove'); } while (page.loading);
page.render('step2-viewcart.png');

// Step 3: Confirm contents
page.evaluate(function() {$('#confirm-cart').click(); });
do { phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove'); } while (page.loading);
page.render('step3-confirm.png');
```

Note that `page.loading` can also be any other boolean condition, for example:

```
do { phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove'); } 
while (page.evaluate(function() {return $("#panel").is(":visible");}));
```

I discovered this approach while working on the [triflejs.org](http://triflejs.org) project (the Internet Explorer version of phantom) trying to emulate calls to `trifle.wait(ms)` inside the PhantomJS environment.

Comment: can `phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove')` work in mobile page?

Comment: @FengYu sure thing. `mousemove` is the right event to use. Phantom (like your desktop browser) doesn't know its a mobile page. All it knows is that its opening a web page and rendering it.

Comment: can I remove `page.sendEvent('mousemove')` in while loop?

Comment: @FengYu If you remove the `sendEvent('mousemove')` you'll get into an endless loop - ie the browser state will never change. Phantom uses the `mousemove` event to trigger an event loop that does a whole bunch of things like loading, rendering dom, checking events and garbage collection.

Comment: I have some problem when use pohantomjs. But I don't know if this is because I use `sendEvent('mousemove')`. This is my post's link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993391/script-error-when-login-in-twitter-using-phantomjs.

Comment: Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

My approach for this scenario is to wait until "something" is done or true.
I highly suggest you to test [waitfor.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js).

**demo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body id="body">

    <div id="thediv">Hello World !</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#thediv').hide();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#thediv').show();
        }, 3000);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**demoscript.js**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 5000, //< Default Max Timout is 5s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof (testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if (!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    //console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    typeof (onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady();
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    //phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof (onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 500); //< repeat check every 500ms
};

if (system.args.length != 1) {
    console.log('invalid call');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    //adapt the url to your context
    page.open('http://localhost:40772/demo.html', function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            waitFor(
                function () {
                    return page.evaluate(function () {
                        return $('#thediv').is(':visible');
                    });
                },
                function () {
                    page.render('page.png');
                    phantom.exit();
                }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

This script evaluate `$('#thediv').is(':visible')`(classic Jquery code) every 500 ms to check if the div is visible.

Comment: Awesome solution. I'm not sure how to apply this for node `phantom`, due to the `Promise` pattern @see https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/issues/431

Answer (score 1):

Inside page.evaluate(), use the **self.loading** property to test for doneness ....

```
var fs = require('fs');
path = '/path/to/file.html';
address = 'http://google.com';    

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access page');
    } else {
        var p = page.evaluate(function () {
            if(!self.loading){ // ah, such beauty
              return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
            }
        });
    fs.write(path, p, 'w');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```