# CasperJS check a page every x seconds until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to check a page every x (configurable) seconds in CasperJS. If a certain page element is present, then the script would continue with some extra steps before exiting. Otherwise it continues checking every x seconds. What code construct can be used for this?

The task is checking a particular eBay store if a (rarely listed) item exists. The question is essentially how to construct a while loop which is compatible with CasperJS promises. It will require refreshing the page.

Comment: Do you need to refresh the page, or just wait for an element to appear? Thanks.

Comment: Might help anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807212/how-to-wait-for-element-visibility-in-phantomjs

Comment: Why don't you start with showing us what you've done so far.

Comment: The task is checking a particular eBay store if a (rarely listed) item exists. The question is essentially how to construct a while loop which is compatible with CasperJS promises. @alecxe it will require refreshing the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since CasperJS' step functions (`then*` and `wait*`) are asynchronous and JavaScript doesn't have a blocking `sleep` function, this is easily solved using recursion.

```
function check(){
    if (this.getHTML().indexOf('some item') !== -1) {
        this.echo("found");
    } else {
        this.wait(x*1000).thenOpen(url).then(check);
    }
}

casper.start(url, check).run();
```

Another way is to use `setInterval`, but when you use it, you will break out of the CasperJS control flow. You will also have to prevent CasperJS from exiting. This is done by passing a callback into `run` (it can be empty).

```
casper.start(url, function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        casper.thenOpen(url, function(){
            if (this.getHTML().indexOf('some item') !== -1) {
                this.echo("found");
                this.exit();
            }
        });
    }, x*1000);
}).run(function(){});
```