# Vue.js not rendering when trying to generate a PDF using Phantom.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, phantomjs, vue.js, vuejs2

In this simple example with hardcoded url my Vue.js components not rendering, plain html get rendered but all places i have a component appear blank.

Phantom.js should work normally with Vue.js?

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
page.open("-----------", function start(status) {
    page.render('test.jpeg', {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Quick vue code for who want to help and do the test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <style media="screen"> body { background-color: grey; } </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        plain text before vue
        <div id="app" v-text="title" />
        plain text after vue
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const app = new Vue({ el : '#app', data () { return { title : 'Vue Title' } } });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for those who want give a try, just install phantom.js and create an ex: text.js and call in terminal.

 phantomjs test.js

Comment: I'm also having issues with vuejs and wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: @Nick i believe if you change to server-side render your vue will work normally with pdf generation. In my case i can't change now for ssr.
If possible for you i've almost sure your pdf will work.

Comment: unfortunately server side rendering for me isn't an option. Thank you.

Comment: @marceloch2 did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @user1012181 sadly no, we finished the project without this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Check your phantomjs version. Phantomjs Version 2.x would work just fine with vuejs.

It's possible that phantomjs is running too quick that the element is not yet available when it reach that part of the code. Use waitForElement or wait to induce a delay before trying to access the element.

Comment: Hi @Jewel thanks. But tried with few approach's, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807212/how-to-wait-for-element-visibility-in-phantomjs#19070446).

But no luck, same result.