# Phantom.js PDF coming as empty for a Vue.js page

Tags: vue.js, phantomjs

[Similar to this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537570/vue-js-not-rendering-when-trying-to-generate-a-pdf-using-phantom-js.) , I am facing issue of Vue.js file not getting rendered in the PDF(empty) generated using phantomjs

Comment: as mentioned in the ticket that you added in your answer the ssr (server side rendering) is the accurate solution to vuejs rendering problems the idea is that vuejs take time to render the page, and that cause these errors it's problem more in SEO when we use vuejs

Comment: server side rendering for me isn't an option.Any other solution. Thank you.