# Take screenshot of site, with just the URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a small and lightweight way to get the screenshot of a website with just the URL. I've heard you can do this with XML/PHP, or even use another service to return the image. However, is there a fast simple way to do this? Preferably in Js? Also, to clarify, my project is going to be dynamically generating these thumbnails.

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php ?

Comment: Perhaps You can have a look at a PhantomJs. It has the ability to take screenshots among other things

Comment: You can't just say "I want to do X. How about languages Y or Z?" You need to do some research into what's possible.

Comment: you could try [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Comment: This is a valid question. How would you dream up a solution for taking screenshots just like that. you wouldn't know where to start in php with this

Comment: I agree that you need html2canvas. Then you render the image like so: document.getElementById("newimg").src= document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");  But first you need the HTML of that URL, if cross-domain AJAX don't work - you 'll need PHP.

Comment: You can use PhantomJS with PHP, take a look here https://github.com/microweber/screen

And here is the api - http://screen.microweber.com/shot.php?url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076297/take-screenshot-of-site-with-just-the-url

Comment: Thanks much for the answers, I will definitely check out your links. PhantomJS seems like the optimal solution. If someone would post that as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with html/php alone. You need a browser to interpret the content on the page and get a screenshot. Some sort of software. OR use a 3party service 
http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/api looks good, I haven't tried them though

Comment: and the downvotes because?

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems similar to what I need but the pricing is kind of a deal breaker. I'll explore other alternatives before settling on this.