# Static caching as image of heavy DHTML-Pages

Tags: php, caching, webpage-screenshot

I would like to create a service, that provides a screenshot of [this site](http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/ffmap/nodes.html), which uses heavy dhtml and is really slow on slower computers, especially on Firefox.

It would be perfect, if that screenshot would be actualized every few minutes, so I could implement it into our Website with an automatic refresh.

On Windows I could use the php-function [imagegrabscreen](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagegrabscreen.php). But that would take the screenshot without the loaded AJAX elements.

How could I delay the Screenshot until all AJAX data is loaded?

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php (which has a really hich ranking, what is the difference to my question? )

Comment: 4 years old question, the rules changed. Oh, voted to close that one too.

Comment: Asking for recommendations of a library is also off topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Web-solution:

You can use [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org) and choose a reasonable modern browser and windowsize.

It also has an API: https://browshot.com/api/documentation

You can specify any size for the thumbnail.