# How to convert HTML page to Image?

Tags: php, html, image

I have a html page http://gthost.dyndns.org/gtfb_final/cam/3097952a5c3a90d7d35.38138446.html. I want to convert it to image (480 X 480). This full html will be converted to an image. Is there any PHP code for that?

Comment: If you have control over the server, you could try the flying toaster java project.

Comment: Duplicate of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php) and many, many more

Comment: I don't think its possible what you're asking. You could use a PDF conversion library using that HTML page as the source. Just Google one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I went through those question threads and also seems like it's not possible in pure PHP. You need to do some stuff in server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this:
[pear.php.net html renderer](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-compatinfo.ref.renderer.html.php)

and for self doing:
[5 Minute tutorial](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/a-simple-html-renderer-in-php/)

for other results search for **html rendering in php** (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Imagemagick and invoke it with **exec** to render HTML into an image.

http://www.imagemagick.org/