# screenshot of HTML5 banner using php/curl, linux

Tags: php, linux, html, api

i want to take a screenshot of HTML5 banner page and save as jpg file. the problem is if i use CURL it gives me blank page, because the HTML5 banner take 2-3 seconds to render the contents. my questions are
is there any possibility screenshot using CURL PHP
Should i use some API to get the screenshot, then which one
Can achive using linux commands

Comment: check this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php i think this would solve your issue

Answer (score 2):

You could use PhantomJS (a headless browser) to open your banner.
BUT PhantomJS is not a fully implementation of a Desktop Browser (like Chrome).
So features like Video won't work.

In that case, you can use Selenium WebDriver to open and get a screenshot, but you need to have X server, or use xfvb.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a library to do that, CURL would only return the source code but without rendering.

[CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) does the job