# How to extract thumbnail of a website in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I want to extract thumbnail of a website  using java.javascript or jquery but not using PHP or .Net.Can I do it because i Surfed on Google and they show that this can only be possible using Java.I have an input box where user will enter the website and I want to show the thumbnail of a website in the div?Is there an plugin or API through which I can do it?

Comment: Just throwing this out there: **Java is not JavaScript**. They are *completely* unrelated (aside from Rhino, which is probably not what you're working with).

Comment: Also, this has been asked a billion times. Perhaps using the search feature on the website will yield proper results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Comment: @ Qix Firstly it is not a duplicate question because I want to get thumbnail using JAVA not PHP and Secondly I know the difference between Java and Javascript I wrote Javascript here because I was thinking if somebody could tell me some API for this as we use API for google maps.If you can't help me it's alright but don't tell me that this question is useless.

Comment: First of all rolling back your edits will only make your question less readable. I improved the wording and grammatical mistakes; I didn't change what was being asked.

Comment: Secondly, you don't explain your use case. How is Java involved in the web page? An applet? A servlet? What is the PHP doing? How do you expect to expose a Javascript API through Java? None of this is explained in your question thus I don't think anyone is going to give you an answer you'll like.

Comment: And where is google maps coming from?

Comment: @ Qix Thank you for voting down my question,I really appreciate it,The reason I rolled back because u linked my question as a possible duplicate that would make my question less readable,I didn't have any objection with you changing the spelling of my question.Secondly with due respect I don't think your english is good beacuse there is no PHP or googlemaps doing in my coding,I just gave an example,I can't post my code here because it is against the policies of my company and it is common sense if I am talking about API or Javascript that means I am using a JSP page and I am using JSTL in it.

Comment: Rolling back a question doesn't un-mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Qix well at least I tried and I became successful because after your edit at top of question the message was printing This is a possible duplicate and now it is not appearing.

Comment: That's not why it was removed.

Comment: @Qix So you tell me why it was removed?

Comment: Go ask [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)...

Comment: If i wanted to get an answer from [meta] why would I ask you?

Comment: @Qix Ok Then I think My rollback would have worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get the thumbnail of a website using Java you can use this free API

http://free.pagepeeker.com/v2/thumbs.php?size=x&url=google.com

Just replace google with your respective link and you will get the thumbnail of your respective website.