# Script to copy website content - not source code

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where the user goes to another website, copies the content, pastes into a text box, and clicks submit. My PHP script parses the content and imports a table into my MySQL database. I am looking to automate this. I know the PHP file_get_contents command will get the source code of a website, but I am looking to get the content as it is displayed on a browser.

The script does not have to be in PHP - I am open to anything. Any suggestions very welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: You want to search google for the term "headless browser".

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: `file_get_contents(SOME_URL)` should give the same HTML as a browser sees, it can't even access the source code unless they expose it instead of the website..