# Simple way to take a screenshot of a web page using PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, screenshot

I have been searching and testing for a while now and I cant seem to find anything that works.

I have tried APIs like Grabzit but it doesnt seem to work for me.

I was wondering if there is a simple way of taking a screenshot of another webpage using Javascript/PHP.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: http://www.devinzuczek.com/2011/08/taking-a-screenshot-with-phpunit-and-selenium-rc/