# Screenshot of specific section of a webpage using code

Tags: javascript, php, image, canvas, save

Is there a way to essentially take a screenshot of a specific section of a webpage when a button is pressed and save the image to my server? For example, when I press the button it saves a "screenshot" with all the content between top:100 top:800 left:200 left:700

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a javascript library [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) that worked great for me in one of my projects. Here is a sample to use.

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        /* canvas is the actual canvas element,
           to append it to the page call for example
           document.body.appendChild( canvas );
        */
    }
});
```

A working demo [here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?0n85l1GB).

Good Luck with this one.

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Thanks, I changed the code a little so it fit what I needed to do but this worked fantastically!