# Allow users to download web page as image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm looking for the easier way to allow users to download a webpage as an image.  Basically I want them to be able to just click a button and it downloads a screenshot of the entire page.

I know there's plugins for browsers to do this, but can't expect all my users to have those installed.

I've been searching for a way to do this and Google doesn't seem to be providing any helpful answers.  Does anyone know how to do this or possibly point me in the right direction?

I'd prefer to use PHP or Javascript to add this feature.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Comment: I'd use a service. [URL2PNG](https://www.url2png.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com) works great.

Comment: Please clarify if you want a PHP or a JS approach. Currently, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct users to an online url to image convertor site. A quick Google search will give you many such options