# PHP imagegrabwindow grabs a blank black image

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Below is the code that I am using to grab the screen shot of the entire webpage.

reference stackoverflow link ([Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php))

When I run this script from browser, All I get is a blank black image and not the screen shot of the webpage. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$Browser = new COM('InternetExplorer.Application');
$Browserhandle = $Browser->HWND;
$Browser->Visible = true;
$Browser->Fullscreen = true;
$Browser->Navigate('http://google.com');

while($Browser->Busy){
  com_message_pump(4000);
}

$img = imagegrabwindow($Browserhandle, 0);
$Browser->Quit();
imagejpeg($img, 'screenshot3.jpg');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to php.net ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php ):

the imagegrabwindow function "is only available on Windows."