# Get website screenshot and use it on image tag

Tags: php

I'm trying to use an `<img>` tag to display a webpage as a thumbnail. I would like the front page of the site to basically be a thumbnail image.

So for example, if I have google.com I'd like to convert the front page to an image and then do something like this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://google.com';
//make this an image some how
echo '<img src="$url_image">';
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: You'd have to screenshot the page, save it to your server, then serve that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: Any chance of building it on the fly instead of saving it to the server? I saw that one but don't necessarily want to save it if I don't have to.

Comment: You'd want to use something like [imagecreatefromjpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) with @chris85 comment to do this on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could use [thumbalizr](http://www.thumbalizr.com/apitools.php) for this also:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
$api = "http://api.thumbalizr.com/?url={$url}&width=250";
echo "<img src='{$api}' alt='thumbnail site' />";
?>
```

Sidenote: It will show a watermark.

[Out](http://codepad.viper-7.com/drEbfT)