# Is there a way to capture a screenshot or element via PHP?

Tags: php

I have a graph that is created using Google Charts.  Is there a way to screengrab a chart that is created by Google Charts  on the backend?  My guess is no, however just wanted to make sure there is no way to grab a front-end feature on the backend.  I've searched for libraries that can do this and it doesn't seem like something like this makes sense. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You can use something like `wkhtml2pdf`

Comment: ImageMagick || wkhtml2image || wkhtml2pdf || html2canvas (JS solution)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php