# Converting HTML to images without installing anything

Tags: php, linux

I want to create a functionality that converts HTML source code of some websites into jpg/png images. I also have to do that on external server - which means I don't know if it has all necessary libraries, and I don't wanna install there too much things, the less the better.

I have found two options:

```
- wkhtmltoimage
- cutycapt
```

But they both require dependencies to install, not to mention emulating server, which sucks.

Is there a way to do this without any external libraries? Thanks!

Comment: you can use old `<canvas>` method. elements inside canvas can be saved as image from mouse right click menu. but IE the only one who couldn't save it as image.

Comment: Hi i think this link has an answer for you.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: use webkit2png.

This saves a clipped image (-C) at 100% scale (-s 1):

webkit2png -C -s 1 -W 1000 -H 1000 --clipwidth 1000 --clipheight 1000 http://t.co
-F only saves a full size image:

webkit2png -F http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Java Library, [Html2Image](https://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/).This simple Java library converts plain HTML markup to image and provides client-side image-map using HTML  element and also supports different image formats such as GIF, PNG or JPEG image.

This library has very handy, simple and sober **API**'s.

Common usage is this:

```
HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();

imageGenerator.loadHtml("<b>Hello World!</b> Please goto <a title=\"Goto Google\" href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>.");
// OR you can fetch HTML from URL
imageGenerator.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/xyz.html");

imageGenerator.saveAsImage("hello-world.png");
imageGenerator.saveAsHtmlWithMap("hello-world.html", "hello-world.png");
```

Which will generate *hello-world.png* image of the HTML and *hello-world.html* file containing client-side image-map .

There are several others API's of this library which you can explore as per your needs.

Comment: Still, I have a php tag in my post

Comment: @khernik, first you must edit your question, specify `php` also.

Comment: @khernik, for process *php* script, you can use **loadUrl(url)** Api of this library which  loads HTML from URL object or URL string.Because when you access *php* script from URL, it returns processed file which is fully HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much possible in linux using `pbmtext`. This tool converts any text into a pbm image file.

For you case,

```
curl -L google.com | pbmtext > google.pbm
```

However, **beware** that this will produce a very large file (several 100s of MB). So you will have to do some post-processing, like converting it into another format or resizing it.