# Create dynamic html page with php

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I need to create new html pages with PHP. What I need is to get a new html page with a canvas inside.

At this moment I capture the canvas from another page with `html2canvas`.

I need this canvas to become the background of the new html page, or just a `100%` width `100%` height picture.

What I have with PHP is this, but I need to capture the picture or just the canvas on fly, and then make something like this:

```
<?php

    $file = file_get_contents("example.html");
    file_put_contents("example.html", $file);
?>
```

How can I do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you're trying to take a screenshot of a page, then use that as the background of another new created page in PHP.

Take a look at this for taking screen shots: [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Once you have your screenshot taken, just use something such as

```
$newpage = 'example.html';
$contents = file_get_contents($newpage);
$contents = "<html><style>background-image: '<?php echo //Your Saved Screenshot ?>'</style></html>";
file_put_contents($newpage, $contents);
```

Comment: Cool, and no problem.